# SF4 + doctrine event

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

I'm playing new Symfony 4. I really like when service use autowire and the component use annotations. I don't must nothing registration in services.yml. Ofcourse I can't solve everything in this way, but I try.

I create simple and test project. When I have Page. Page has "slug" field. This value is generated with field "title". I created special service (App\Service\Slug). 
I would like to generate slug in event when page is create or update. To the event I should be to injected the slug service.

I would like to create one listner for only one entity - Page. I found: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html In this solution the event is run for all entities and I must create configuration in services.yml.

```
App\EventListener\PageListener:
  tags:
    - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }


class PageListener
{
    /**
     * @var Slug
     */
    protected $slug;

    /**
     * PageListener constructor.
     *
     * @param Slug $slug
     */
    public function __construct(Slug $slug)
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;
    }

    public function prePersist(
        LifecycleEventArgs $args
    ) {
        $page = $args->getObject();
        /** ... */
        $slug = $this->slug->get($page->getTitle());
        $page->setSlug($slug);
        /** ... */
    }
}
```

In this solution the event is run in all enitites and I must check the instance.

I remeber that In sf2.8 I could add adnotation to entity (EntityListeners) -> https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html In this version symfony I see this adnotation but it doesn't work. I found only old cookbook: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineBundle/entity-listeners.html

How should I do it correctly?

In the conclusion I want to create a simple doctrine event, which work for only one entity and its configuration is minimal.

**edit:**
When I tested, I found solution which "works":

Entity:

```
/**
 * Class Page
 *
 * @package App\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductRepository")
 * @ORM\EntityListeners("App\EventListener\PageListener")
 * @ORM\Table(name="pages")
 */
class Page
```

services.yaml:

```
App\EventListener\PageListener:
  tags:
    - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener }
```

PageListener:

```
public function __construct(Slug $slug)
{
    $this->slug = $slug;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function prePersistHandler(Page $user, LifecycleEventArgs $event)
```

I don't know how or I can't removed configuration in "service.yaml".

Comment: I'd consider not updating the slug on page update. It makes sense to update the slug as well to not get a title/slug mismatch, but it might break your SEO + old links users have saved.

Comment: It's only test project. I try to create simple doctrine event :) I want update one field when the object is saved

Comment: PrePersist and PostPersist annotations still work did you try that ?

Comment: @Smaïne: Yes, when I added annotation in method is ok. I wonder if I must to register event in services.yaml file becasue in entity I added `@ORM\EntityListeners("App\EventListener\PageListener")` It looks like duplicate registraction. But maybe I must to register event in service.yaml - class will be event and EntityListeners run this event when I work on this entity.

Comment: I try minimize the configuration and understand how it works.